# Enable "linestyle" functionality for Gnuplot in Octave?

Tags: qt, plot, gnuplot, octave, fltk

In Octave there is the problem that with fltk and qt greek letters in figures are not printed, only with gnuplot as graphics_toolkit. But then with gnuplot all lines are solid, no dashed lines.
I found a page which says that other linestyles can be enabled:

http://wiki.octave.org/Enable_%22linestyle%22_functionality_for_Gnuplot%27s_x11_terminal

I added the lines there to my ~/.Xdefaults and did *xrdb -merge .Xdefaults* as said there,
but no success.

I am running octave 4.0.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Any hints?

Thanks

Karl

Comment: Btw the 4.2 release will be able to print greek letters. If you want to include your prints in scientific paper using Latex, I suggest using epslatex or psfrag, see http://wiki.octave.org/Printing_with_FLTK for an example.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you cannot do it for the time being. But if you're happy for workarounds, your best choice seems to be to create an image of greek text and use that as your title etc.

Here's a way. Go to the [codecogs online latex editor](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php) and write your greek title using their tool in tedious math mode :p If you copy the link to the resulting image, you can use that straight into `imread` if you prefer to saving a file (this also makes your code automatic such that it can be used in a script, assuming you have an internet connection.

e.g. I used the following math tex to generate the greek title:

```
\Pi\acute\alpha\lambda\iota~\sigma\kappa\alpha\tau\acute\alpha~\tau\alpha~\kappa\acute\alpha\nu\alpha\mu\epsilon~\mu\epsilon~\tau\alpha~E\lambda\lambda\eta\nu\iota\kappa\acute\alpha~\rho\epsilon~\mu\alpha\lambda\acute\alpha\kappa\epsilon\varsigma
```

and then using the link to the resulting image (or saving locally)

```matlab
>> image  % draw octave logo
>> greektitle = imread('http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?%5Cdpi%7B300%7D%20%5Chuge%20%5CPi%5Cacute%5Calpha%5Clambda%5Ciota%7E%5Csigma%5Ckappa%5Calpha%5Ctau%5Cacute%5Calpha%7E%5Ctau%5Calpha%7E%5Ckappa%5Cacute%5Calpha%5Cnu%5Calpha%5Cmu%5Cepsilon%7E%5Cmu%5Cepsilon%7E%5Ctau%5Calpha%7EE%5Clambda%5Clambda%5Ceta%5Cnu%5Ciota%5Ckappa%5Cacute%5Calpha%7E%5Crho%5Cepsilon%7E%5Cmu%5Calpha%5Clambda%5Cacute%5Calpha%5Ckappa%5Cepsilon%5Cvarsigma');
>> greektitle = repmat(greektitle,[1,1,3]); % make rgb so unaffected by colormap
>> axes; imagesc(greektitle); axis equal off; 
>> P=get(gca,'position'); set(gca,'position',[P(1),0.9,P(3),0.1]); % place on top
>> saveas(gcf,'out.png','png')
```

[image]